# AccessViolationException when typing in Textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, access-violation

About a week ago a program I'm working on began crashing with an AccessViolationException whenever I typed into a certain textbox. I've reduced it to this test case, but I'm out of ideas:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Start
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    <STAThread()>
    Public Shared Sub Main(args() As String)
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.Run(New Start())
    End Sub

    Private txtNotes As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Public Sub New()
        Me.txtNotes = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtNotes.Multiline = True
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.txtNotes)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I build this program using Visual Studio, it crashes if I type into the textbox (always). If I build it using `vbc.exe Start.vb /target:winexe /main:Start /out:Start.exe`, it works fine.

Additionally, I've found that removing either of these lines stops it from crashing using Visual Studio:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles()
Me.txtNotes.Multiline = True
```

I've already done a repair installation of Visual Studio, and used `sfc.exe` to check for corrupted system files. I've tried searching for existing solutions to this problem, but haven't found anything. What could be causing Visual Studio to build a broken executable? Is there some setting that would do this?

Edit: I'm also running AVG antivirus at the moment. I recall that there was an AVG update around the time these crashes began. As per one of the comments below, disabling AVG, and then scanning the executable prevents it from crashing. This would seem to indicate that the problem lies with AVG.

Comment: Ongoing discussion on this problem on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13570be7-49d9-47f1-878d-a3f208356d09/multiline-textboxes  None of the workarounds are acceptable for our case, so I will keep exploring solutions.

Comment: I've replaced AVG with Panda antivirus on my computer, and my program no longer crashes.

Comment: Great - I've used the provide feedback link on the AVG website to let them know about the problem. I'll report back if/when I hear anything.

Comment: This is now in the AVG dev teams tracking system with reference CORE-1497

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the same problem with a few of our clients' installations on Windows 7. Our product is C# with WinFoms and .net 4.0. Typing in a mutli-line text box under WinForms crashes an AccessViolationException. You can paste text in the box and delete it too, just not type. Single line text boxes are fine. We also found that removing Application.EnableVisualStyles() cured the problem.

Another way to fix it without code changes is to right click the program icon and change the compatibility settings to run the program for Windows 7.

Comment: Further, we have noticed that all of our affected clients run AVG anti-virus. Disabling AVG real-time protection and performing a manual virus scan on the EXE also cured the error (not a long term solution). However, we have a lot of clients with AVG who do not have the issue.

Comment: I can confirm that I am using AVG antivirus, and that this workaround seems to work. Looks like I might be switching antivirus products.

Comment: From the last post on here https://support.avg.com/answers?s=textbox%20multiline#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Windows&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=906b0000000D5rsAAC it would appear that AVG have issued a fix for this though I haven't had a chance to confirm this with our affected users

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, and I'm running AVG too.

As a temporary solution before AVG provides a fix, you can add the .exe file to AVG's list of exceptions. I can confirm that this removes the AccessViolationException shown in Visual Studio.

1. Open AVG, go to Options
2. "Advanced settings..."
3. Exceptions
4. "Add exception"
5. Choose "Application or File"
6. Select your executable file (in my case, I used .../bin/Debug/myexe.exe)
7. I checked "Even when the file has been changed or updated"
8. Finally, I checked all of the three options at the bottom: "Resident Shield", "Manual and Scheduled Scan", and "Identity Protection"

I did not perform any change regarding visual styles or compatibility mode, as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Solved it by unchecking Enable XP visual styles.

Some background in case it helps anyone else.  Application was originally created in VS2010.  Moved up to VS2015RC.  Everything worked fine.  Problem occurred after a reinstall of the OS (Win7).  Even the old version of the application would not work, although it did continue to work on all the other Win7 desktops, including a new install.  If anyone knows why, it would be interesting.